# How check that Cluster sharding is started properly?

Tags: scala, cluster-computing, akka, sharding, akka-cluster

I want to check whether ClusterSharding started on not for one region. Here is the code:

```
def someMethod: {
    val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem", ConfigFactory.load())
    val region: ActorRef = ClusterSharding(system).shardRegion("someActorName")
}
```

Method `akka.contrib.pattern.ClusterSharding#shardRegion` throws `IllegalArgumentException` if it do not find shardRegion. I do not like approach to catch `IllegalArgumentException` just to check that ClusterSharding did not started.

Is there another approach like ClusterSharding(system).isStarted(shardRegionName = "someActorName")?
Or it is assumed that I should start all shardingRegion at ActorSystem start up?

Comment: Did you try to call start method for "someActorName"  before shardRegion (scaladoc: "Retrieve the actor reference of the ShardRegion actor responsible for the named entry type. The entry type must be registered with the #start method before it can be used here.")?

Comment: I need to check whether `start` method is called. Not call it first.

Comment: but how you can call start method without ActorSystem (i see it private in your example)?

Comment: Can you please close this and mark as resolved by selecting an answer, it if satisfies you?

Comment: @Cherry did you found a solution rather than Exception check ?

Answer (score 1):

You should indeed start all regions as soon as possible. According to the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3-M2/contrib/cluster-sharding.html):

"When using the sharding extension you are first, typically at system startup on each node in the cluster, supposed to register the supported entry types with the ClusterSharding.start method."

Startup of a region is not immediate. In particular, even in local cases, it would take at the very least the time specified in the akka.contrib.cluster.sharding.retry-interval (the name is misleading: this value is both the initial delay of registration and the retry interval) parameter of your configuration before your sharded actors can effectively receive messages (the messages sent in that period are not lost, but not delivered until after a while).

If you want to be 100% sure that your region started, you should have one of your sharded actor respond to an [identify](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.1/index.html#akka.actor.Identify) message after you call cluster.start . Once it replies, you are guaranteed that your region is up and running. You can use a [ask](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/pattern/package.html) pattern if you want to be blocking and await on the ask future.